# Suggested edits under my name I never made?

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

I have recently discovered how to check whether a suggested edit has been approved or not. Just out of curiosity, I took a look at the rejected suggestions, and I found this one: *[Retrieve array in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1623145)*.

I am sure I didn't write that, because I haven't used the type attribute for a script tag in at least one year. I checked the [revisions of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15149991/revisions), and the differences are similar to the edit which was made one minute later. Then I supposed it was an irrelevant bug, and I didn't pay more attention to the issue.

However, I was a bit suspicious so I searched for another rejected suggested edit. Then I found this completely nonsense suggestion that I am **completely sure** I didn't write: [MySQL/PHP Order By Where](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1599094). The only difference is the *"Fingers crossed there is a simple resolution to this..."* addition at the beginning, [which was already written by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15079636/revisions).

Do you know if something similar has happened before? Is it possible to remove this two suggested edits from my activity?

Comment: Probably a timing/race condition issue.

Comment: @LanceRoberts That's what I thought at first time, but two race conditions to the same user in 4 days seemed very unlikely to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In your first example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1623145), you submitted an edit at 3:03:04Z. A user reviewed the edit, decided to edit it, and unmarked the "Suggested edit was helpful" box. That causes your edit to be rejected by the Community user.

Why did the reviewer reject your edit and substitute his own? Well, you didn't fix up the display of the array values, and missed some grammatical mistakes, but it looks like the reviewer substituted a poorer edit in place of yours. I would have improved your edit as well, and since your changes were positive, I would have marked them as helpful. Though do try to clean up as many issues as you can in edits.

In [your second example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1599094), you submitted your suggestion about 30 seconds after [John Conde submitted his edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15079636/revisions). John has much rep, so his edits were accepted immediately. You wrote your suggestion against the original version of the question (that contained *"Fingers crossed there is a simple resolution to this"*), but the diff for your suggestion, rendered for reviewers, was against the version of the question current when you submitted, *without* that sentence.

So yeah, a timing issue.

Comment: I've discovered a [third example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1623060) in which happens the same as in the first one, and also the first reviewer is the same user. I remember the suggested edit for the MySQL question (thanks to the insane risk to SQL injection in the code), but I'm pretty sure I didn't do any of the other two. Could that be possible?

Comment: @A.Rodas: possible, but less likely - you normally see an edit with *exactly* the same timestamp as yours, when this happens. I don't see that here. The fact that it's the same reviewer says something, but it's not conclusive to me. It *was* a bad edit - it looks like you just deleted the second code block. Is that what you remember doing?

Comment: No, I don't remember either of the JavaScript posts. Also they are [two isolated edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1019227/a-rodas?tab=activity&sort=suggestions): the previous one was two hours earlier, and the next one the day after. I'm starting to think they have been wrongly attributed to me.

Comment: Well, I don't know what this says, @A.Rodas, but the comment on that suggested edit uses the same (misspelled, so more of a fingerprint) phrase that you've used recently. It seems likely that the *comment* is yours, at least.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote `Formatted` in the second example but I usually misspell it, so the comments are mine. I'm still wondering about the content, but there is no point in trying to figure it out. Thanks for your time.